# Is it possible to create CDF document with Mathematica 7?

Tags: cdf-format, version-7

As far as I can understand from the exemplary videos [here](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/information-kit/c) and [here](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) the minimal version of *Mathematica* that has the inbuilt possibility for creating CDF documents is *Mathematica* 8. But is there some a way around this?